# Unable to load js and css files in node.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

This is html page.I'm calling this page from node.js server i.e, app.js.Here I'm unable to load socket.io.js,bootstrap.js,bootstrap.css pages.

My index.html:

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type ="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/bootstrap.css" />


<div id="progressbar">
</div>

<script>
  var socket = io('http://localhost:8085');
  socket.on('connect', function(){});
  socket.on('message', function(data){
    $('#progressbar').progressbar({
    maximum: 100,
    step: JSON.parse(data).percent
    });
  });
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){});
</script>
</html>
```

My app.js code :

```
var app = express ();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
http.listen(8085, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:8085');
});

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
 res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
//res.send('Hello World!');

});
```

In firebug,I'm facing this 
[image]

Comment: Can you post your `app.js`, the part where you include `express.static`?

Comment: Maybe also the folder structure where your app is running from

Comment: please check the app.js code

Comment: Make sure the path is correct. Can you see the file from http://localhost:8085/javascripts/socket.io.js ?

Comment: yes,I'm able to see the file

Comment: can anyone please help me out ... I'm really stucked over here

Comment: post your console output

Comment: Try to use tilde in path: `src="~/javascripts/socket.io.js"`

Comment: No its not working with this :src="~/javascripts/socket.io.js"

Comment: In the screenshot I see that bootstrap is loaded. Why do you think thet are not loaded?

Comment: I'm getting a blank screen.And I'm getting this error in firebug :Reload the page to get source for: http://localhost:8085/javascripts/socket.io.js

Comment: The firebug console shows any error?

Comment: No it is not showing any error.But I'm getting null response

Answer (score 2):

You have set up incorrect paths for static files.

In your case, you'll need to use this:

```
app.use('/javascripts', express.static(__dirname + '/javascripts'));
app.use('/stylesheets', express.static(__dirname + '/stylesheets'));
```

Now, whatever files are in *javascripts* and *stylesheets* folders will load as static files.

Your current method of using static files:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

This will load everything that's beneath *public* folder as static files, so you would need to move the *javascripts* and *stylesheets* folders there if you want that to work.

Comment: Which of the options did you try?

Comment: I tried by changing to the above said code .It did not worked for me.Actually at this path,I'm getting the file http://localhost:8085/javascripts/socket.js

Comment: so in index.html,I changed like this,<script src="http://localhost:8085/javascripts/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:8085/javascripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:8085/stylesheets/bootstrap.css" />

Comment: Create a very simple project example with this problem and put it on GitHub, I'll check it out.

Comment: Sorry, host it somewhere so I'm hopefully not the only one looking.

Answer (score 0):

change your view engine to html and modify the code like below :

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'public'));
app.set('view engine', 'html');
```

and change the sendfile method :

```
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../YOUR_FOLDER_NAME/public', 'index.html'));
```

EDITED::

change the index.html file:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/test.css" />
```

Comment: check the edited answer. you don't need to put  the socket.io.js in javascript folder manually.just add the script and remove '/' before stylesheets and javascripts in script and link file .

Answer (score 0):

This is the app.js. (based on @Andrius' solution) I was able to make it running on http://localhost:8085. index.html stays the same.

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
http.listen(8085, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:8085');
});

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
//app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

//test
app.use('/javascripts', express.static(__dirname + '/javascripts'));
app.use('/stylesheets', express.static(__dirname + '/stylesheets'));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//app.use('/', routes);
//app.use('/users', users);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
 res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
//res.send('Hello World!');

});
```